# C++ - how to pass an array into a function that takes an int * type, within a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I usually use vectors in C++, but in a particular case I have to use arrays which I'm not used to.  If I do this:

```
// GetArraySize.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include <conio.h>   // remove this line if not using Windows

int main(void)
{
  int myArray[] = { 53, 87, 34, 83, 95, 28, 46 };

  auto arraySize = std::end(myArray) - std::begin(myArray);

  std::cout << "arraySize = " << arraySize << "\n\n";

  _getch();    // remove this line if not using Windows

  return(0);
}
```

This works as expected (`arraySize` prints out as 7).  But if I do this:

```
// GetArraySizeWithFunc.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include <conio.h>    // remove this line if not using Windows

// function prototypes
int getArraySize(int intArray[]);

int main(void)
{
  int myArray[] = { 53, 87, 34, 83, 95, 28, 46 };

  int arraySize = getArraySize(myArray);

  std::cout << "arraySize = " << arraySize << "\n\n";

  _getch();    // remove this line if not using Windows

  return(0);
}

int getArraySize(int intArray[])
{
  auto arraySize = std::end(intArray) - std::begin(intArray);

  return((int)arraySize);
}
```

On the line `auto arraySize = std::end(intArray) - std::begin(intArray);`
 I get the error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::end" matches the argument list, argument types are: (int *)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I should mention a few things:

-I'm aware that with C++ 17 I could use `std::size(myArray)`, but in the context I'm working in I can't use C++ 17

-There may be other / better ways to write a `getArraySize()` function, but moreover I'm trying to better understand how old-style arrays are passed into / out of functions

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?"  Well, `int main(void)` should be `int main()`.  And `return(0);` should be `return 0;`.  And `return((int)arraySize);` should be `return (int)arraySize;`. Instead of a C array, you should use `std::array`.  If you insist on passing in a C array, you should also pass in its length (if its length is something you care about).  So `int getArraySize(int arraySize) { return arraySize; }`, which is a bit redundant.

Comment: Don't do an array to pointer decay https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-array-to-pointer-decay.html.

Comment: If this is C++, `main(void)` should be replaced with `main()`. Also the return type should be `int`.

Comment: Also, you should avoid casting by using proper type and if you really need some cat, then you should use C++ cast like `static_cast`.

Comment: `std::size(x)` will only works when `std::end(x) - std::begin(x)` works so using C++ 17 would not help. C style arrays do not carry their size across function as the decay to pointers.

Comment: Thanks Phil1970, after doing some more research on this, it seems the answer is what I was attempting to do isn't possible with old C-style arrays since they decay to a pointer to the first element upon a function call.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `std::size` yourself:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto size(const T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

usage:

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << "size: " << size(arr);
}
```

---

Note that you need to pass a *reference* to the array, since simply passing `T[]` will actually make you pass a `T*` to the first element of the array. That will not preserve any infromation regarding the array's size.

Comment: Note that it doesn't chain.  You can't have `main` call `void DoSomething(int arr[]) { int sz = size(arr); ... }`.

Comment: Correct, but the OP seemed like he wanted to implement `getArraySize` and mentioned that he wants `std::size`. My note at the bottom should somehow indicate that it won't work if you pass `T[]`, since passing `T[]` is pretty much the same as passing `T*`. I also emphasised the usage of a *reference to an array* to make that point clear.

Comment: Your post is great, just that the follow up question will be why it doesn't work in the case I mentioned.  Then the response will be "You should be using `std::vector`" (which is what should be used in _almost_ every case in C++ instead of a C array).  Which I know you know.  :-)